# Entering wrong username and password still django authenticate it as correct

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, authentication, django-views

I am trying to create a login page in Django when the login details are filled in correctly it redirect to a certain page the problem I am facing is that when I enter wrong username or password Django authenticate them as correct and redirect it to another page my login code is as follows

```py
def loginpage(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        use=request.POST.get('username')
        pas=request.POST.get('password')
        
        
        user=authenticate(request,username=use,password=pas)
        if user is not NONE:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('data')
            
        else:
            messages.info(request,'Username or Password is incorrect')
            return render(request,'login.html')
```

Even after entering the username that doesn't even exist in the database Django authenticate as right and doesn't show the error that I am expecting

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you passing `request` as the first argument to the `authenticate()` function? That parameter is set to None by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have uppercase `NONE` instead of `None`. You must have accidentally imported `NONE` from `pickle` or some other library, and that's why it's validating instead of raising an error. Check your imports at the top of the file and change to `if user is not None`.